# Django: Return errors form in json to template and receive with JQuery

Tags: jquery, django

I have this views that send a return with erros after form validation:

```
def update_window(request):
   if form.is_valid():
   # save the form
   else:
      data = dict((key, [unicode(v) for v in values]) for key, values in form.errors.items()) 
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data))
```

This return give the following errors for send to template.

```
{'postals_before': [u'Field required.'], 'postals_after': [u'Field required.']}
```

The form is inside a Twitter Bootstrap Modal Window:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'update_window' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
  </form>
```

How to receive the errors dict in the modal window with jquery as the form is not being sent by ajax?
Regards!

EDIT!

Solution for validate fields in form without a return errors form in views:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

I remove the return in views and create this validation in template:

```
$(function () {
$("#form").validate({
    // Defining the rules
    rules:{
        postals_before:{
            required: true
            number: true
        },
        postals_after:{
            required: true
            number: true
        }
    },
    // Defining the messages for each rule.
    messages:{
        postals_before:{
            required: "Enter the amount of postals on display.",
            number: "Only numbers."
        },
        postals_after:{
            required: "Enter the amount of postals placed.",
            number: "Only numbers."
        }
    }
});
});
```